# Do the Blu-ray episodes replace the TV episodes on the Internet once they've been released?

Tags: anime-production

Because of God Eater, I got to know that the episodes in the Blu-ray often differ from the episodes recorded on TV. As the Blu-ray is being released after the series has been completed, the producers often modify the animation of certain scenes.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2HkC.jpg)'s an example where you're able to see these modifications.

But are there any legal streaming sites that sometimes or commonly replace the TV version of an anime with the improved Blu-ray version once the latter one becomes available? How does especially Netflix, who's recently been publishing a lot of older animes (that are not currently airing on TV), handle this? Does it just publish the Blu-ray version or does Netflix stick with the TV version?

Comment: TV episodes do not often differ, but always. It's just that the degree of the differences varies. Usually streaming sites do not update their TV version, but it happens occasionally. CR did replace their TV version with a lower quality version a day after release for the longest time, though, to save money.

Answer (score 1):

It depends; I do know that Funimation re-uploaded Highschool DxD season 3 to the blu-ray version, as an example; they previously had the censored TV version, and now it's the uncensored version. Meanwhile, Crunchyroll still has the TV version.

Comment: For Crunchyroll, I think it depends on the series. For example, Crunchyroll's Puella Magi Madoka Magica seems to be the BD version because in episode 2, Mami's apartment is pretty well-decorated ([TV vs BD comparison](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/File:Madoka_BD_5.jpg)), but Crunchyroll's Mekakucity Actors seems to still be the TV version because episode 9 on Crunchyroll still has that cringey uncanny valley CGI sequence ([TV vs BD comparison](https://kotaku.com/you-wont-believe-how-different-this-tv-anime-looks-1663102684)).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it depends on whether the websites own the rights of the anime's Blu-ray version, because the TV and Blu-ray versions act as separate entities for commercial rights.